# Cakephp Expression is missing operator (IS, IS NOT) with null value

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.0

When I delete the item from the cart and click delete button. It actually deletes the item but it gives me this error.

My code as follows:

```
<td>
    <?= $this->Form->create(null,[ 'url'=>['controller' => 'Carts', 'action' => 'delete', $cart->id]]); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->hidden('cart->id', ['value'=>$cart->id]); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->submit('add to cart'); ?>
</td>
```

Carts controller as follows:

```
  public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $cart = $this->Carts->get($id);
        if ($this->Carts->delete($cart)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The cart has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The cart could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
```

Comment: Please check the code.

Comment: Could you please show `$this->Carts->delete()` method?

Comment: it the delete method in carts controller.

Comment: @Dmitry please check.

Comment: Whenever you receive an error, please post the _complete_ error message (including filename and line number), and include the related stacktrace (you'll find both in your CakePHP `/logs/`) - thanks!
ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: Maybe you error is at index method, where you com after delete.

Comment: I have deleted this line and its deemed solved             .return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);